# Reusing a parameter in hibernate Restrictions.sqlRestriction?

Tags: java, hibernate

Let's say I would like to do

```
SELECT * from T where X < 12345 AND Y < 12345
```

using Restrictions.sqlRestriction. The constant that X and Y are being compared to is the same in my case. Ideally, I would want to pass it along to the sqlRestriction only once, and reference it by its index in the argument list. Is this possible?

I could pass it along twice, like this:

Restrictions.sqlRestriction("X < ? AND Y < ?", {12345, 12345}), but I'm asking if there is a more elegant syntax, Similar to how C#'s WriteLine allows stuff like

```
Console.WriteLine("This {0} appears here also {0}", 12345)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the hibernate functions instad writing the query "by hand".

For example:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT t FROM T t WHERE t.X < :maxValue AND t.Y < :maxValue");
query.setInteger("maxValue", 12345);
query.list()
```